# I am stuck with the situation as given in the image

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I am stuck as below image. Can this be solved ?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes. This is a 3-cycle of the corners, and all three of those corners also need a twist in the same direction. Both of these things can be done individually.
I put that position into [Cube Explorer](http://kociemba.org/cube.htm), and it gave the move sequence `R' F U2 F' R  F R' U2 R F'`.

Comment: Could you recommmend a good link to a description of the sequence notation?

Comment: @BmyGuest This standard notation (Singmaster notation) is explained in lots of places, for example in the [speedsolving.com wiki](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/3x3x3_notation).

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved.

This seems to be the antisune case which can be solved with the algorithm:

> R U2 R' U' R U' R'

Comment: welcome here, nice first answer +1! edited spoilers for you ;)

Comment: That anti-sune will orient the corners, but not permute them. It will also perform a 3-cycle of the edges, so after the anti-sune you will still have to be permute both edges and corners to solve it.